# Why I get error during push to Git Android Studio?

Tags: java, git, android-studio

Everything was good and all my pushes to remote server were successful until today. I started to receive error:

> Remote URL test failed: getLastSuccessful failed. token:
>   a7995c09-4e90-44f4-b143-67445d302f75, userName: my_server_adress,
>   client: http://localhost:63342/RPC2 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Invocation failed Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
>   http://localhost:63342/RPC2 at
>   org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.GitSSHXmlRpcClient.getLastSuccessful(GitSSHXmlRpcClient.java:200)
>   at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.authenticate(SSHMain.java:201)
>   at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.start(SSHMain.java:162) at
>   org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.main(SSHMain.java:125) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
>   http://localhost:63342/RPC2 at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
>   at
>   org.apache.xmlrpc.DefaultXmlRpcTransport.sendXmlRpc(DefaultXmlRpcTransport.java:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:72)
>   at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:194) at
>   org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:185) at
>   org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:178) at
>   org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.GitSSHXmlRpcClient.getLastSuccessful(GitSSHXmlRpcClient.java:196)
>   ... 3 more Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure
>   you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

maybe this error was caused by the last update of AS? What I have to do for pushing code changes?

Comment: Which Git service are you using? Do you have an access token set up? It is possible your token has expired and you need to recreate it.

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory. "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists." Was there any change wrt access rights? Can you verify if you're facing the same issue with GIT CLI? Or do you rely on SSH auth and have changed your key recently?

Comment: @DogLover, this service was set up on the server of my company, then I was given address for pushing, I have never use access tokens for pushing

Comment: @DhruvilVaghela, I don't about rights changes, but I think that any rights were changed, what is Git CLI? I use SSH and I have key for this purposes

Comment: By Git CLI, I mean using Git from terminal. See if you're able to push to given repository using command line. If yes, probably some issue with config in Android Studio Git plugin.

Comment: @DhruvilVaghela, I have solved my problem via changing in preferences from native ssh to built-in, I don't know why, but it is working :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko I read your comment, and I check my AS, it's already built-in, so I changed to native, and it works

Comment: @FrankNguyen, so it's good or bad? ;)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko It's good because at least I can fix the issue :D

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue with the latest update of AS, and I managed to solve it by going in Settings > Version Control > Git
Then I switch "ssh executable to "native"" (was "Built-in" before)

Comment: I cannot see that option in AS4